# How do you change the top-padding for a view in iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I want to change the top padding of a view to 80 when a button is toggled. How would this be done? Basically I want there to a space of 80 between the top of the view and the text.

Comment: This depends on a number of things: Do you draw the view yourself (in `drawRect:`) or is a compound view (it has a label as a child)? Do you use Auto Layout or not?

Comment: I have something like this: `self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];`

Comment: How did you add the text to the view?

Comment: @Julia: You need to give more details when you ask these questions so we can help you. So, how does the view draw text? Do you draw it yourself in `drawRect:` or does the view have a `UILabel` that draws the text? When the view retains its size, is there room below the text? That is, is the text at the very bottom or is there some free space where the text might move to? Please _edit_ your question and tell us as much about your view as you can. Right now, we can only guess.

Comment: (Right now, most of your questions suffer from this lack of details which is why you get few answers. If you invest more time in your questions more people will answer and/or you get higher quality answers.)

Comment: Sorry, I am relatively new to iOS development.

Comment: It's not about iOS or development per se, but about being precise. So, if you want answers, then edit your question and give us the informations we have asked you about your view and all the details you think might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using autolayout, then the easiest thing to do is to create a constraint for the distance between the text and the top of the view. You can connect it to a NSLayoutConstraint in code, and set the constraint.constant to the new value when the button is pressed.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *paddingConstraint;


// Somewhere after the button press
self.paddingConstraint.constant = 80;
```

Oh, and you will probably need to update the layout by calling this -

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Well, if you aren't using autolayout you would just want to create a new frame for the label to move it down. Something like this - 
self.label.bounds = CGRectMake(self.label.bounds.origin.x, self.label.bounds.origin.y + 80, self.label.bounds.size.width, self.lable.bounds.size.height);